# Как вывести наименовании единицы веса opencart 3?

Tags: opencart3.x

**v 3.0.3.3**

В админке есть единицы веса, добавил нужные, пытаюсь вывести в родном плагине latest (новые поступления), для этого сделал:

1. контроллер

   'weight_class'      => $result['weight_class_id'],
2. twig

   {{product.weight_class}}

Результат получаю, но не тот, заместо наименование единицы (например - кг/г/л/мл) получаю ее порядковый номер (1/2/3/4....)

Как сделать чтобы выводилось **наименование** единицы веса?

Answer (score 1):

Сделал сам, забирайте кому надо

```
'weight'      => (float)$result['weight'],  //(вывели сам вес (численное значение с округлением))
'unit'        => $this->weight->getUnit($result['weight_class_id']), // (а тут вывели наименование его единицы веса)
```

В twig:

```
Вес: {{weight}} {{unit}}
```